# Parse Nested Parentheses in Abstract Syntax Tree with Javacc

Tags: expression, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, javacc

I am trying to parse expressions such as `a*(4+5)` in my parser to build the abstract syntax tree.

```
void addSub() : {}
{
    mulDiv() ((<ADD> mulDiv()  )| (<SUB> mulDiv() ) )*
}
void mulDiv()  : {}
{
    factor() ((<MUL> factor() )|( <DIV> factor() ))*
}
void factor() : {}
{
     (numeralLit() | booleanLit() | LOOKAHEAD(2) functionCallExp() | idUse())
     //TODO add () support
}
```

however, if I add an expression such as

```
void parantheses() :{}
{
<LPAR>
addSub()
<RPAR>
}
```

and place it in `factor()`, I get an error saying a recursion as occured (parantheses uses addSub()). How would I go about the structure so that it could prevent recursion?

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem.  I rewrote `factor` as `void factor() : {}
{
     numeralLit() | booleanLit() | LOOKAHEAD(2) functionCallExp() | idUse()
     | parantheses()
}` and made reasonable assumptions about the other nonterminals. And got no error message. If you still have a problem, post a more complete example.